Databricks Compute Event Log - Event Type Reference
Is there official Databricks documentation about the event log of compute instances? Most of the entries are quite obvious - but for some of them it would be good to have some extra context.
Just to be clear - I refer to this screen. You get there from Compute > Click on a Cluster > Event Log tab

The only documentation I could find was in the Prefect Documentation (https://docs.prefect.io/latest/integrations/prefect-databricks/models/jobs/#prefect_databricks.models.jobs.ClusterEventType).

Azure Databricks offers three types of logs for monitoring compute-related activities:
Compute event logs: These logs record events related to the lifecycle of compute resources, such as their creation, termination, and any configuration changes.
Apache Spark driver and worker logs: These logs are useful for debugging purposes.
Compute init-script logs: These logs are important for troubleshooting init scripts.
This section covers compute event logs and driver and worker logs. For more information on init-script logs.
Know more bout Init script logging.
As you mentioned you need more info about the event log of compute instances?
The compute event log captures key events in the lifecycle of compute resources, whether triggered manually by a user or automatically by Azure Databricks.
These events can impact the overall operation of a compute resource and the jobs running on it.
For details on the types of events supported, check out the Clusters API data structure.
Event logs are kept for 60 days, which aligns with other data retention periods in Azure Databricks.
Reference: Manage compute & Compute event logs
